# Disable Autoplaying of Videos in Safari on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I've tried disabling autoplaying of videos in Safari with these settings:

https://geekchamp.com/how-to-disable-safari-autoplay-videos-iphone-ipad-ios-ipados/

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253275903

Videos are still starting without me touching the video. How do you disable autoplaying of videos in Safari?

Comment: Do you have an example of a video that plays? Because turning that off should turn off any site's preview video. Note: any site that wishes may ignore that setting and play videos. There are some ways around it (ublock origin on desktop and vinegar on ios) where you can surgically block videos on some sites (I have blocks for cnet.com for example.)

Comment: imdb.com and youtube.com are autoplaying videos

Answer (score 0):

The **Auto-Play Video Previews** setting is advisory, sites delivering ads or video previews (Netflix) will ignore it.

For mobile, there is [Vinegar](https://apps.apple.com/sg/app/vinegar-tube-cleaner/id1591303229) that blocks Youtube very well for me. IMDB is more difficult. There is a guide to blocking [inside the IMDB app here](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/apps/apps-imdb/disable-autoplay-video-previews/). Blocking in Safari would require a monthly fee to an ad blocker like [1Blocker](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/1blocker-ad-blocker/id1365531024) or someone to write a script for [Userscripts](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/userscripts/id1463298887). At present, there are no free methods.

Desktop is easier, just install [Ublock Origin](https://ublockorigin.com/) then install these filers:

- IMDB [taken from here](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/dyhwim/how_to_block_ads_in_imdb_tv/).

```
||imdb.com/tr/*pageHit$xhr,redirect=noopjs,domain=imdb.com
||fls-na.amazon.com/$xhr,redirect=noopjs,domain=imdb.com
*$media,redirect=noopmp3-0.1s,domain=imdb.com,3p
```

- Youtube should be automatically handled by ublock origin.

Comment: In Safari on iOS what does 1Blocker do that other blockers don't?

Comment: It has an option to hide elements, the default ones are to block cnet videos. You could write one for youtube to hide the autoplay element.